# Compatibilidad entre .Net Core 2.0 y .Net Framework 4.7

Tags: .net, .net-core

Estoy creando unas bibliotecas de uso general (dll's), para reutilizarlas en proyectos .Net Core 2.0 y .Net Framework 4.7. Quiero tener proyectos .Net Core en linux y proyectos .Net Framework 4.7 para Windows. Una biblioteca desarrollada con .Net Core 2.0 se puede utilizar en proyectos .Net Framework 4.7 normalmente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es una librería que tenga como target `.NET Standard`, no `.NET Core`.

`.NET Standard` es una especificación de la cual varios frameworks pueden implementar.

En el caso de .NET Standard 2 es soportada por los siguientes frameworks o versiones superiores:

- .NET Core 2.0
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Mono 5.4
- Xamarin.iOS 10.4
- Xamarin.Mac 3.8
- Xamarin.Android 7.5
- Universal Windows Platform vNext (Aún no soporta .NET Standard 2.0)

A su vez una librería creada en .NET Standard puede ser referenciada por esos frameworks o versiones superiores.

Sin embargo lo más recomendable es que apuntes a la versión más baja posible que puedas apuntar, de esta manera tu librería será compatible con mas plataformas y versiones anteriores de las mencionadas.

Para más información de la tabla de compatibilidad revisa: [.NET Standard - .NET implementation support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)